# How to know if a TextView is in animation or not?

Tags: android, textview

upon onClickListener, I am starting an animation on textView (icon)

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils
          .loadAnimation(activity.getBaseContext(), R.anim.rotate_refresh);
icon.startAnimation(anim);
```

on clicking again, I want to check, if the icon is animating (rotating) , keep it that way or else start the animation again.

I want to know how can I check textview is in animation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe try something like this

```
Animation animation = icon.getAnimation();
if(animation != null && animation.hasStarted() && !animation.hasEnded()){
    //do what you need to do if animating
}
else{
    //start animation again
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This line will let you know if the TextView is animated

```
Animation animation=textView.getAnimation();
```

Answer (score 0):

It will most probably work for you as you want to do.

```
boolean isInBetweenAnim = false;
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        isInBetweenAnim = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        isInBetweenAnim = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

So whenever a animation starts you will have `isInBetweenAnim` true and for rest you will have it false. Easily check the value of  `isInBetweenAnim` in `onClick` of your button and you can code for it.

Hope it Works ! Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple views that can start an animation on one view , you must focus on animated view, not animation.

I had multiple info imageViews that shows help text in a textView. To avoid multiple animations on textView, I used Arun's approach:

```
    if (helpTextView.getAnimation() == null) {
        helpTextView.startAnimation(helpAnimation);
    }
```